# Is there a way to disable a specific llvm lld warning?

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, lld

I'm getting the following warning from llvm 6.0.0 `lld` while linking to the `libiomp5.so` which I'm getting pre-built from the llvm 6.0.0 ubuntu 14.04 download ([here](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html))

```
warning: found local symbol '__kmp_gtid' in global part of symbol table in file {some_path}/libiomp5.so
```

As far as I can tell this is an ignorable issue for me (everything still works anyway). I don't want to disable all warnings, or disable treating warnings as errors. How can I tell the linker to ignore just this warning?